# Overflow x-auto in Angular 5 material table

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I need to make responsive table even that would render in mobile view without breaking up. In order to make it work, I used standard HTML table link below

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Have a look at sample: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp

It worked great but recently switched to Angular 5 table which does not have API for responsive design. How can I make add overflow-x auto to angular table? The sample angular 5 table:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-ibmgv2
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean it's not responsive? In your example, the table will smoothly shrink down to 0 width without ever needing an overflow-x. Even if you add `overflow-x:auto`, it will always be useless because the table will go all the way down to 0 with without ever overflowing its parent container. If that's not being responsive, I don't know what is :)

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes I want to make it responsive without shrinking it. Need to keep the defined width such 50px. If total width is lower then show overflow-x auto. How can I acheive that in angular 5 material table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per your demo, just add following `CSS` to your css file.

```
.example-container.mat-elevation-z8 {    
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.example-container .mat-table.mat-table {
  min-width: 450px;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it worked like a charm. Thanks so much. Did not expect such simple solution!

Comment: Thanks you, for such positive comment.

Comment: This works but does cause issues with using a sticky header row.

Answer (score 1):

```
.table-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.mat-table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0px;
}

.mat-row,
.mat-header-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.mat-cell,
.mat-header-cell {
  word-wrap: initial;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  line-break: unset;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

check this link it will help you.

Credit Source -
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8680#issuecomment-388358839